# check how many time a key value exist in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check a `key=>value` in a array , how many times exist.
i am giving an example here. to check in it whether Array[DriverLocation][driver_id] = 83 is appear 3 times in following array.
this is i am going to do that if same key value is exist then remove this inside array and go ahead to fetch siblings data.
example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 85
                    [zip_code_id] => 43
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:25:34
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 43
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 15478
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Arman
                    [last_name] => Kumar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 43
                    [zip_code_id] => 42
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:37:12
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 30215
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Pawan
                    [last_name] => Kumar
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 42
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:37:28
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 30215
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 26
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 43
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:43:59
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 43
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 15478
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 41
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 6
                    [created] => 2015-05-21 05:23:53
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Whittier
                    [zip_code] => 90607
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you want to check each key?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow what you intend to do. Do you want to loop through and if you find a driver id that's been seen before, ignore and move on? Or do you want to remove the entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can from PHP5.5 use 2 times the [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function. This function puts all the values of that key in an array.

```
$driver_ids = array_column(array_column($array, 'DriverLocation'), 'driver_id');

print_r(array_count_values($driver_ids));

Result:
Array ( [85] => 1 [43] => 1 [83] => 3 )
```

Or PHP version before 5.5:

```
$driver_ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['DriverLocation']['driver_id'];}, $array);

print_r(array_count_values($driver_ids));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `array_key_exists()`  function.

Comment: Not really what OP wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_filter` and `count` for this:

```
echo count(array_filter($array,function($element){
    if(isset($element['DriverLocation']['driver_id'])) {
        return $element['DriverLocation']['driver_id'] === 83;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you just want the first entry of `83` as driver id, you could gather all the values first, put them inside another container and only put the first ones there and use it as a key.

Just add a condition wherein, if its not yet there, put it inside, if its there already don't include, so in the end you'll only left with the first unique entry of each drivers.

```
$drivers = array();
foreach($data as $k => $values) {
    if(!isset($drivers[$values['DriverLocation']['driver_id']])) {
        $drivers[$values['DriverLocation']['driver_id']] = $values;
    }
}

// $drivers = array_values($drivers); // optional array re-index
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VWtUkD)